# MySQL Query to choose all but the most recent datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have a row in my db table that is datetime. How can i write a query to only all rows except one (the most recent).

I would have used

```
ORDER BY col_name DESC LIMIT 1
```

if i was choosing only the most recent.. but i actually require all but the most recent.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a guarantee that only one row has the most recent datetime? I see a fair number of bugs due to people assuming datetimes are unique, when they are not.

Comment: Why don't you just fetch all records and ignore the one record in your PHP code? And also, is your data guaranteed to have unique datetimes?

Comment: LIMIT 2? Wont that take only the second row?

Comment: There isn't a great MySQL solution for this without doing multiple queries or specifying lots of criteria. You're better off filtering out the first result in your client.

Comment: @joshp Were are not expecting heavy traffic, and moreso the datas are entered into the database manually. It's for contents and it's display.

Comment: LIMIT 2 would take two rows at most. You might select all but the row with the max value in that certain column, like: `...WHERE col_name < (SELECT MAX(col_name) FROM table_name)` or you might exclude the row with the highest value in primary key since it's `auto_increment`ed at each new row.

Comment: @hakre It is actually  `ORDER BY col_name DESC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615`

Comment: @MostyMostacho: Quite, yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select all rows but the first:

```
ORDER BY col_name DESC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615
```

See [13.2.9. `SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) which explains the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if there are two max values then you'll be getting the max value anyway.

Comment: You're missing that TS is not speaking about values but rows.

Answer (score 0):

Title says:

> MySQL Query to choose all but the most recent datetime

If have duplicated dates you'll have to go for:

```
select * from t
where val != (select max(val) from t);
```

This is because if there are 2 max values then limit will only filter the first one and you'll get the other max value in the resultset.

Comment: Even if some rows have the same value for the timestamp, one of them is more recent - thats how relational databases work.

Comment: Are you saying you can't have 2 equal datetime values?

Comment: No, exactly the opposite: You can have two equal datetime values, but one of those rows is more recent.

Comment: And how do you determine which of those equal datetime values is more recent?

Comment: @hakre I'm not sure if I understand correctly.  What you mean is that the values for two columns in two separate rows may be equal, but that the rows were not inserted at the same time, and thus one of them is more recently added, correct?

Comment: exactly. otherwise there would be one row only (which isn't the case)

Comment: @hakre Ah ok.  Is ORDER BY field guaranteed to order rows such that if two fields are equal, the more recent row comes first?

Comment: AFAIK yes. but that is not officially guaranteed. Offically there is no order in the data next to the one you specify, so the outcome is undefined. You might want to use incrementing primary keys and sort with those, too to ensure you get the add-order properly done.